# to use iphone on xcode do I need gsm card

Tags: iphone, xcode, gsm

what do I have? I have mini mac and Im starting to program using xcode, I dont have Iphone yet, so, if I want to make app to take pictures but Im having problem to work with emulator, so, if I buy a Iphone 4s for example, can I use it in xcode without gsm card? because I have other phone that I use to program android, so, I dont want to buy another gsm card just to put in iphone.

Comment: why do I get -2 on this question?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on [Use iPhone without SIM](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/is-it-possible-to-use-an-iphone-without-a-sim-card-as-an-ipod-touch)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need a GSM card to install the applications you write onto your iPhone, but you do need a `developer certificate` to do that, which costs `99$/year` if I'm not mistaken.

Though you could have easily found this out using Google...

Comment: thanks for fast answer, I've bought the developer certificate, the problem is the emulator is not helping me to go so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can just buy a used iPhone off of eBay and then use that one. You don't need a GSM card in the phone itself. But for first activating it you need to have a gsm card in there.
But that does NOT need to be an activated SIM card, just any SIM that fits the slot will do, at least did it for me.
I'm using two different iPhones for my app development, because they both have different iOS versions. 
Sure the simulator would be able to cover that, but sometimes it's just better to bring an app with you on an actual phone, especially when testing wifi- or gps related apps. Plus it makes it easier to show it to people and maybe secure the one or other future customer.

I use code-snippets and stack overflow a lot for my dev, almost 100% of the time you find really good questions here, that have been answered already (multiple times).

Good tutorials you can find under
ray wenderlich and on youtube.

Hope that helps!

Happy coding